# how can resolver MacOS Error : react-native-vector-icons:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. React-Native

Tags: macos, react-native, android-studio

I could open the android emulator before, but now I can’t open it

how can I do ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

add jdk path `org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_144`
to gradle.properties

And also

try to wipe data of your emulator